# My ubuntu does not appear in boot menu

Tags: boot

I had dual boot my Laptop windows 8.1 and Ubuntu it was successfully installed but when I tried to update it,  "Kali GNU/Linux Desktop" appeared instead of Ubuntu Desktop, so I re-install Ubuntu but this time it does not appear in boot menu and when used Windows it seems to be that the partition I made for Ubuntu is properly made What should I do? By the way I installed easyBCD in my windows

Answer (score 1):

Prepare a Ubuntu live cd and boot from it (Do not choose to install it again).

Open a terminal and mount the partition your Ubuntu Installation is on. If you are not sure which it is, launch GParted (included in the Live CD) and find out. It is usually a EXT4 Partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

Replace the XY with the drive letter, and partition number, for example: 
`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`.

Now bind the directories that grub needs access to to detect other operating systems, like so.

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

Now jump into that using chroot.

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Install, check, and update grub.

```
grub-install /dev/sdX
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
update-grub
```

You only need to add the drive letter (usually a) to replace X (do not use the partition number), for example:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
```

Now grub is back, all that is left is to exit the chrooted system and unmount everything.

```
exit &&
sudo umount /mnt/sys &&
sudo umount /mnt/proc &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev &&
sudo umount /mnt
```

Shut down and turn your computer back on, and you will be met with the default Grub2 screen.